# How to create a loop to write json files with two arguments from different lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I would like to modify my code with a for loop for:

- first to create a list of files to create `fnames = []`
- secondly to create a list of `json_dics = []`

I currently have a separate variable for each `file`

```
file_xx = f'{root_path}/{output}/{file_name_xx}.{json_ext}'
```

and separate variable for each `json_dics`

```
json_dic_xx = [{"test": "test", "test1" : "test1"}]
```

I use functions to write data to files

```
def save_to_json(json_dic, data_to_save):
    with open(data_to_save, 'w', encoding= utf_8) as json_file:
        json.dump(json_dic, json_file, ensure_ascii= False, indent=4, sort_keys= True)

save_to_json(json_dic_xx, file_xx)
```

I would like to create a for loop that, using the `save_to_json()` function, would take two `arguments`, one from the `fnames = []`, the other from the `json_dics = []`, and write the data to the appropriate files accordingly.

EDIT: my solution after making corrections by Rubén Pérez

```
output_file_names = ['filename01', `filename02', 'filename03']

fnames = []
for fname in output_file_names:
    fnames.append(f'{root_path}/{output}/{fname}.{json_ext}')

json_dics = [[] for _ in range(len(fnames))]


for i in range(len(fnames)):
    save_to_json(json_dics[i], fnames[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(xx):
    save_to_json(json_dics[i], fnames[i])
```

EDIT: You can also create a loop for the first lines:

Assume you have every `file_name_xx` in a list `filenames = []`.

```
fnames = []
for filename in filenames:
     fnames.append(f'{root_path}/{output}/{filename}.{json_ext}')
```

You can do the same with json_dic

Comment: thx, I did as you suggested, I created a list `output_file_names = []` where I have the names for the files I want to save, then with a `for fname in output_file_names` loop I add the full `path` and `extension` to the filename, additionally using `json_dics = [[] for _ in range(len(fnames))]` I create this list how many files to save

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip() function to iterate over both the json_dics list as it will help with that. Below is an example:

```
json_dics = [json_dic_01, json_dic_02, json_dic_03, json_dic_04, json_dic_05, json_dic_06, json_dic_07]
fnames = [file_01, file_02, file_03, file_04, file_05, file_06, file_07]

for json_dic, fname in zip(json_dics, fnames):
    save_to_json(json_dic, fname)
```